# How can I align and distribute objects diagonally in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, distribute

I have a word that I converted to outlines, and I want each object to be aligned diagonally to the artboard, although nothing seems to work. How can I do that?

Example

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Gonna need to see at least a crude example of what you want.

Comment: That's what I was talking about: https://imgur.com/a/eylPLRz

Comment: @AlexandreAndrejow do any of the existing answers help? If yes, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Vikas I will do it. You guys really helped me. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a different approach to achieve something similar to what I show in my other answer.

If you just want to distribute the letters purely based on their geometry, you can do the following:

- Select your rotated, expanded word.
- Select *Object > Ungroup* to make the letters individual objects.
- Roughly place the letters like you want them.
- In the *Align* panel make sure to click *Align to Artboard* and then click *Vertical Distribute Space* followed by *Horizontal Distribute Space*.

[image]

Note that although this distributes the letters mathematically precise, the different shapes of the letters might force you to manually nudge the letters around until achieving a balanced look.

Comment: You can just move the D and Y to place them where you want them and then distribute the spacing for everything. `:)`+1

Comment: @Scott, as far as I can tell because the letters have different widths you need to place them in the order you want them to have. Else they end up in scrambled order where in this example the A is placed left of the E.

Comment: Might be newer AI version. It *should* merely be based upon the stacking order.... but if logic were always followed Adobe would be out of work :)

Comment: @Scott, I assumed that, but it seems stacking order has no influence, only initial left position. Now that I think about it, I mostly use distribution to clean up distances between objects I already placed and I never worry about stacking order so it must have been like this for a while.

Comment: heh.. just tried in CS6... **I am wrong** `:)` It **was** based on stacking order at one point, maybe CS4... then they broke it. Your'e right.. mish-mosh of placements unless you slightly tweak things first.

Answer (score 2):

- Select your rotated, expanded word.
- In the *Transform* panel, copy the value in the *Rotate* field.
- Select *Object > Ungroup* to make the letters individual objects.
- Enter *Object > Transform > Transform Each*. In the *Rotate > Angle* field, write a minus and paste in the angle you copied before.
- Press *OK* to rotate the individual letters.

[image]

Comment: Ah, just realize that I perhaps got this the wrong way around! Anyway, the same method could be used to have diagonal letters along a horizontal line.

Comment: to be fair, the question isn't very clear. This is how I read it too. +1 from me